# Did any country condemn Senegal for importing so much goods from North Korea?

Tags: north-korea, senegal

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_North_Korea

According to Wikipedia, in 2021, 20.4% of North Korea's exports went to Senegal, almost as much as China's share of North Korea's exports. I was surprised a country would import as much goods as Senegal, especially since Senegal is more vulnerable to sanctions than China. Did any country condemn Senegal for importing so much goods from North Korea?

Comment: There's some massive variation in sources.  The CIA cites exports of 4.8billion.  But the source for "senegal = 20.4" comes form the OEC which lists less than 200 million.  PRK trade has collapsed. Senegal continues to import refined oil (about $40 million) WHich is 1/10 of what it imports from Nigeria.  Basically 20% of not much is still not much.